# How to generate test data Uber developers api history endpoint?

Tags: uber-api

I am integrating our app with a person's Uber history and would like to test the code, but I don't have any Uber trips in my account.  How can I test my API calls?

So far, I've used the sandbox API (e.g. https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/sandbox/requests/) to create/update requests and I can query individual requests, but none of the requests show up when i call the history endpoint (https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/history)

How does one go about testing this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 1):

good question. "At this time, most of the endpoints in the Sandbox environment are proxied straight to the production environment." - https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/sandbox

So in this case, I believe there is not any 'fake' or 'test' data when calling the Sandbox for the history endpoint. This is a limitation and an improvement that could be made in the Uber sandbox environment. To get data, here, I believe you would need to take a ride or auth in a user that has taken past rides. Thanks.